# How to loop over a list of children found inside a single scala.xml.Node

Tags: scala

I'm pulling down some markup from a url and returning a single scala.xml.Node like so ...

```
  def doGoogleSearch(query:String) : scala.xml.Node = {
    val tmpUrl = "http://www.google.com?q="
    val tmp = tmpUrl.concat(query)

    val url = new URL(tmp)
    val conn = url.openConnection

    val sorce:InputSource = new InputSource
    val neo = new TagSoupFactoryAdapter
    val input = conn.getInputStream

    sorce.setByteStream(input)
    val markup = neo.loadXML(sorce)
    input.close

    return markup
  }
```

Next I want to loop through each child element inside the markup and what I have so far only seems to print 2x (yet this is a huge amount of html coming back).  What am I missing here?

```
def loopThroughChildren(markup:scala.xml.Node) : String = {
    for (i <- 0 until markup.child.length) {
      //println(??
    }
  return ""
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to loop through only the immediate children of the node, or do you want to recurse through all the children of node, and the children of those again, and the children of those..., i.e., all subnodes of the tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyways, here's a recursive function for you:

```
def processNode(node: Node) {
  if (node.isInstanceOf[Text]) println(node.text)
  node.child foreach processNode
}
```

This will print the contents of all text nodes in the document. If you feed it with e.g.:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Foo</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It will produce:

```
Welcome
Foo
```

Answer (score 5):

As a simple solution, you could say

```
markup.child.map { child =>
  // child is a scala.xml.Node
}
```

and possibly use recursion, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Or equivalently

```
for(child<-markup.child){
 // child is a scala.xml.Node
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will take a command line argument (filename) and print all tag labels found:

```
import scala.xml._
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object XmlTagLister extends App {
  require(args.length == 1, "You must provide an XML filename to be analyzed.")

  val data = XML.loadFile(args(0))

  @tailrec
  def collectTags(elems: List[Node], tags: Set[String]): Set[String] =
    elems match {
      case h :: t => collectTags((h \ "_").theSeq.toList ::: t, tags + h.label)
      case Nil => tags
    }

  val allTags = collectTags((data \ "_").toList, Set())

  allTags foreach println
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
onetag
AnotherTag
anothertag
```

(XML tags are case sensitive)