# How to traverse up a single child node using scala.xml.Node

Tags: scala, xml-parsing

Expanding on a question I asked earlier about how to iterate over a collection of nodes in scala.xml.Node found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748098/how-to-loop-over-a-list-of-children-found-inside-a-single-scala-xml-node)

I wanted to take this 1 step further and ask how I could look up to a previous child inside a recursive function to get a value once I hit a specific situation

For example (the markup is here)

```
<html>
    <head class="foo">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Foo</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

With my current implementation (thanks to @[knut-arne-vedaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50572/knut-arne-vedaa))

```
def processNode(node: Node) {
  if (node.isInstanceOf[Text]) {
      if (node.text.contains("Welcome"))
      {
        //then inside here I want to go up to the prev element (head) and pull the class 
      }
    }
  node.child foreach processNode
}
```

I want to add another conditional to get the text "foo" from inside the class section

Any idea what I could add inside this if statement to pull this value directly?  Also how can I return the String value from this fx? a break w/ a simple return line or ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the parent of the Text node in your example is actually the <title> node.

Since Nodes don't have references to their parents, one way to access them is just to pass them with you when walking down the tree, like this:

```
def processNode(node: Node, parent: Option[Node]) {
  if (node.isInstanceOf[Text]) {
      if (node.text.contains("Welcome"))
      {
        println("Node: " + node)
        println("Parent: " + parent.getOrElse("[toplevel]"))
      }
    }
  node.child foreach { n: Node => processNode(n, Some(node)) }
}
processNode(xml, None)
```

Of course, this becomes unwieldy when you want to climb back up the tree to an arbitrary level.  One approach to this is to wrap your nodes in a `SuperNode` that has an optional parent reference.

```
case class SuperNode(current: Node, parent: Option[SuperNode] = None)
```

For convenience, make an implicit function to convert nodes to SuperNodes in the default case of no parent.

```
implicit def nodeMakeSuper(n: Node) = SuperNode(n)
```

Now you can navigate up the tree an arbitrary number of times, like this:

```
def processNode(node: SuperNode) {
  node.current match {
      case n @ Text(t) if t.contains("Welcome") => {
          println("Node: " + n)
          node.parent match {
              case Some(p) => {
                  println("Parent: " + p.current)
                  p.parent match {
                      case Some(gp) => println("GrandParent: " + gp.current)
                      case None => println("No grandparent!")
                  }
              }
              case None => println("No parent!")
          }

      }
      case _ => // these aren't the droids you're looking for
  }
  node.current.child foreach { child: Node => processNode(SuperNode(child, Some(node))) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you keep going in this direction, you should use an [XML Zipper](http://szeiger.de/blog/2009/12/27/a-zipper-for-scala-xml/). I think [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) has one (it has one, but I'm not sure if you can use it with XML).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something with the value *only* if it is inside a node with a certain attribute, you can do it the other way around: first find all nodes with the given attribute, then do the relevant processing on them.

You can find all nodes with a "class" attribute of "foo" like this:

```
xml \\ "_" filter { _.attribute("class") == Some(Text("foo")) }
```

EDIT: You use it like this:

```
val markup = <html>...etc
val filtered = markup \\ "_" filter { _.attribute("class") == Some(Text("foo")) }
filtered map processNode
```

If you want to *return* some value from the processing you need to do it differently, but your question is not clear in regards to that.

Comment: How could I use this w/ the above processNode method or would this be a method all its own?  Also how could I print out the filtered list? When I do the filter (as you have it above) and do a println(xml) I still get the same markup returned (appearing that no filter was applied)